# Получение номера ряда ячейки

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Всем привет. Ситуация такова: у меня есть таблицы (Table View) и одна ячейка (Cell). Число рядов определяется автоматически по самому типичному методу:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [data count]; // data - это объект-массив
}
```

В каждом ряду стоит кнопка (Button). Мне надо реализовать метод, который при нажатии кнопок во всех рядах что-либо запускал, например, выводил бы определенную надпись. Полагаю, что нужно как то работать с indexPath.row, но не знаю как.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Ис интересует использование именно UIButton или достато тампнуть по ячейке?

Comment: Vitaly, именно UIButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации таких вещей не обязательно получать номер строки ячейки. Куда проще сделать это с помощью тегов, которые нужно переопределить в методе cellForRowAtIndexpath

В моем случае код выглядит так

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView {cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
            static NSString *const CellId = @"Cell";
            CheckLabelCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];

            cell.checkButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    }
```

А дальше уже писать код, отталкиваясь от тега кнопки, например

```
-(void)On:(int)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    UIImage *Normal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"main.png"];

    if (sender == 7) {
        [self.checkButton setBackgroundImage:checkNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"bool0"];
         Req0 = NO;
         self.Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем вопросе отсутствует код класса ячейки. Да и информации о `UITableView` и его делегатах маловато. Также неизвестно, что за данные Вы храните. 
В таком случае предположим, что у Вас есть такой интерфейс класса данных:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyData : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* text;
-(instancetype)initWithText:(NSString*)text;

@end
```

С реализацией:

```
#import "MyData.h"

@implementation MyData

-(instancetype)initWithText:(NSString*)text {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.text = text;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

В Вашем UIViewController должно быть такое свойство:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<MyData*>* dataArray;
```

Его Вы, к примеру, инициализируете в `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.dataArray = @[[[MyData alloc] initWithText:@"First text"],
                   [[MyData alloc] initWithText:@"Second text"],
                   [[MyData alloc] initWithText:@"Third text"]];
```

И затем сразу обновляете `UITableView` (надеюсь, что у Вас есть ссылка `tableView` на Вашу таблицу):

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Необходимый минимум методов `UITableViewDelegate` и `UITableViewDataSource` выглядит так:

```
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setupWith:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] controller:self];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.dataArray.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 100.0;
}
```

Код интерфейса ячейки таблицы:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyData.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

//Ваша кнопка
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton* btn;
-(void)setupWith:(MyData*)data controller:(ViewController*)controller;

@end
```

Реализация:

```
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"

@interface MyTableViewCell ()

//Ваши абстрактные данные
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyData* data;
//Ссылка на контроллер, где размещена таблица (скорее всего Вам это пригодится)
@property (weak, nonatomic) ViewController* controller;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        [self createButton];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        [self createButton];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)createButton {

    self.btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
    self.btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor;
    [self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.btn];
}

-(void)onBtnPressed:(UIButton*)sender {

    //Здесь Вы можете вывести на экране неободимый текст или произвести иные действия
    UIAlertController* alert = [[UIAlertController alloc] init];
    alert.message = self.data.text;
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    }]];
    [self.controller presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}

-(void)setupWith:(MyData*)data controller:(ViewController*)controller {

    self.data = data;
    self.controller = controller;
    [self.btn setTitle:self.data.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

@end
```

В итоге Вам не нужно получать порядковый номер ячейки. Храните необходимые данные в самой ячейке, и тогда Ваш код заработает и будет понятен остальным.

Comment: Что-то мне не очень понятно все это. Как компьютер понимает, на кнопку какого ряда ячейки мы нажали (ячейка то одна)? И все таки, мне нужно вывести определенный лейбл при условии нажатия кнопок всех рядов. 

Если я пишу такой код, то он срабатывает при нажатии на любую одну кнопку, что логично:

Comment: @Bandicoot Вы собираетесь добавить больше кода в вопрос?

Comment: код, о котором я говорил в комментарии выше:

-(void)comleted {
    
    
    if (checkReq == YES) {
        _checkComplete.text = @"CHECKLIST COMPLETED";
        _checkComplete.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if (checkReq != YES) {
        _checkComplete.text = @"";
    }
}

checkReq - BOOL переменная

Comment: Не получается, у меня слишком низкая репутация. Я могу с вами как то еще связаться?

Comment: @Bandicoot Что за ошибка? Вы сайт chat.stackexchange.com. посетили?

Comment: Да. Он пишет "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here"

Comment: Оповещения приходят

Comment: @Bandicoot Я где-то слышал, что можно зарегестрироваться на 15 сайтах сети и тогда у Вас будет достаточно репутации.

Comment: Не, что-то ни в какую. Ладно, я сам попробую еще поломать голову и разобраться. Спасибо за усилия

Comment: @Bandicoot А Вы на других сайтах сети регистрироваться пробовали? CodeReview например?

Comment: @Bandicoot Раз уж нас с Вами в чат не пускают, значит добавьте побольше кода в вопрос, а то с Вашими тремя строчками сложно понять, что должно в итоге получиться.

Comment: Я нашел решение проблемы. Вопрос закрыт, спасибо